# Find radius of an inscribed circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

I have a following problem:

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVaNW.png)

I have been trying to solve it for the last 2 days, but haven't got any luck so far.

I was trying to create two systems of equations for two points where the inner circle intersects the two quarter circles. I have also taken into account that points where the inscribed circle intersects the quarter circles have the same y coordinate and that they are symmetrical about the line $x = \frac12$.

What I have got so far is (assuming that $x_1$ is the x coordinate of the left intersection point and $x_2$ - of the right intersection point, $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circle and its center is at $(\frac12, r)$ ):

$$x_1^2+y^2=1$$
$$(x_1-\frac12)^2+(y-r)^2=r^2$$
$$(x_1-1)^2+y^2=1$$
$$(x_2-\frac12)^2+(y-r)^2=r^2$$

Unfortunatelly, no matter how I tried to simplify, rearrange and solve these equations I always end up with something like $0 = 0$, so I can't get the exact result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the right-angled triangle with these three vertices: 1) the bottom-left corner, 2) the centre of the inscribed circle, 3) the midpoint of the bottom side. The three sides lengths are $r$, $1/2$, and (the hypothenuse) $1-r$.

Comment: You can find the answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4595910/japanese-temple-geometry-problem-radii-of-inner-circles-inside-quarter-arcs)

Comment: @peterwhy Thank you, I've got the answer with your help! :)

Comment: @user376343 Yes it does, thank you.

Comment: In both peterwhy's hint and the other thread, it is taken as given that the line connecting the bottom left corner and the center of the inner circle also passes through the point of tangency between the two circles. This is what gives the hypotenuse as $1-r$. But it is not obvious that this must be true.